# Is there a way of casting a pointer to an array type?

Tags: c++, c++11

C arrays are somewhat difficult to understand syntactically in C++ and can take some getting used to.  Although a 1D array decays to a pointer:

```
void fn1(int x[2]) {}
void fn2(int*x) {}
```

`fn1()` and `fn2()` have the same function signature.

An array actually does have a type that includes how many elements are in the array.  As in:

```
void fn(int (&)[2]) {}
```

`fn()` will only accept a 2 element int array.

Thing is, I can only see that the array of a fixed number of elements can only be generated by stack, file scope or struct/class allocation with that signature:

```
int twoElementArray[2];
```

If I were to dynamically allocate it on the heap, I can't seem to get the same signature.  I thought that I might be able to cast it, but without success:

```
int (&array)[2] = reinterpret_cast<int(&)[2]>(new int[2]); // FAIL!
```

Any ideas as to how this might be accomplished if at all?

---

**EDIT:** Although I selected an answer, it actually doesn't actually cast anything, but uses a definitely better method then casting (better not to cast if not required IMO).  However, it technically doesn't answer the question since the question asked if there's "a way of casting a pointer to an array type?"  The answer is yes.

```
int (&array)[2] = *reinterpret_cast<int(*)[2]>(new int[2]); // SUCCESS!
```

Note that I don't necessarily recommend doing this, but it does answer the question.  If I needed to convert a pointer to an array type though, that would be how to do it.  Read the picked answer for a better solution when using `operator new[]`.

Comment: you could throw in template and make int FIXED_SIZE = 2.

Comment: @Infested: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.  Could you explain further and perhaps add an example?

Comment: if fn1 only accepts a fixed size of the array, then simply make it a template function and it should get two things , int[] , int FIXED_SIZE = 2, then you can have int x[FIXED_SIZE]

Comment: @Infested: `fn1()` was part of my explanation as to how arrays work in C++ for the uninitiated.  Yes, I could do: `void fn3(int* array, size_t FIXED_SIZE) {}` or alternatively `void fn3(int[] array, size_t FIXED_SIZE) {}` which is a common workaround.  However, I was trying to utilise the type system to stop the decoupling of the array from it's size.

Comment: have you tried doing int [] x ?

Comment: @Infested, again I don't understand what you are asking.  Example?

Comment: That's not valid C++, that's Java.

Comment: and that day hath come, when java took complete control over me.

Comment: Your code is illegal in C++ because `int*` and `int(*)[2]` are different pointer types and there is no legal way to cast from one to the other. Deferencing the `reinterpret_cast` above is _undefined behavior_. Please see the _strict aliasing rule_.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you'd want to do something like this:

```
// allocate an array of one int[2] dynamically
// and store a pointer to it
int(*p)[2] = new int[1][2];

// now initialize a reference to it
int(&array)[2] = *p;

// delete the array once you no longer need it
delete[] p;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.  For the heap, a two-dimensional array `int[M][N]` decays to `int(*)[N]`.  To pass it by reference, dereference it (see `m` below):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func(int (&x)[2])
{
    cout << x[0] << ' ' << x[1] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    // on the heap
    auto m = new int[1][2];
    m[0][0] = 1; m[0][1] = 2;
    auto n = new int[1][3];
    n[0][0] = 4; n[0][1] = 5; n[0][2] = 6;

    // on the stack
    int o[2] = {7,8};
    int p[3] = {9,10};

    func(*m);
    //func(*n); // doesn't compile, wrong size
    func(o);
    //func(p); // doesn't compile, wrong size
}
```

Output:

```
1 2
7 8
```

Comment: +1 for using the proper terminology `decays`.  I corrected my question to use the same terminology.

Answer (score -1):

Based on Mark answer, this could be better:

```
template <typename T>
void func(const T &x)
{
    cout << x[0] << ' ' << x[1] << endl;
}
```

the only bad think is that this code is valid:

```
cout << x[3] << endl;
```

Comment: Sorry, this answer is just wrong.  You have just made a template function that takes a const ref of any type.  It doesn't take an array at all.  Go and try to compile it.  You probably meant something along the lines of `template <typename T> void func(const T (&x)[2]) {...}` or `template <typename T, size_t N> typename std::enable_if<(N>=2)>::type func(const T (&x)[N]) {...}`.  However, that's also assuming that I want to take in any type and not just an int, which isn't what the question asked.